# ng-repeat for array of object and single object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am quiet new to AngularJS and i am reading an XML file that sometimes contains single record or sometimes multiple records.

When i have multiple records, ng-repeat works perfectly as it iterates through array of object but when i have only one record it is not considered as an array (checked through angular.isArray()).

Now i am wondering, how i should deal with this issue.

**ng-repeat code**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="lessons in dataSet.module.lesson | partition:1">
                        <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="lesson in lessons">
                            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <div class="panel-title row">
                                        <a href="" class="col-sm-12" ng-click="expandLesson(lesson);">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <span class="col-sm-10">

                                                    Section #{{$parent.$index * 1 + $index + 1}}: {{lesson.title.__cdata}}
                                                </span>
                                                <span class="col-sm-2 text-right">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

When i see html in elements, its commented out in case of single entry in XML File.

**Log for single object**
    Object {meta: Array[11], resource: Array[3], changes: Object, module: Object, title: Object…}

**Log for multiple objects** 
    [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: Please show how you are processing the xml. Should be easy enough to always make it an array

Comment: Using xml2json.js for that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast your data in array to be sure it is one.

Simple, yet hacky way: `[].concat(yourVar);`.

Clearer way: `yourVar = yourVar instanceof Array ? yourVar : [yourVar];`